# Batch - Convert a line in a text file from integer to ascii

Tags: file, batch-file, text, ascii, data-conversion

I have a file (file.txt) containing just one line (I have concatenated all the lines in one).
So I have the following line:

```
85;048;048;057;048;055; 045 ;84;048;048;057;055;055
```

And I would like that file.txt containing the ASCII conversion of each number delimited by

```
;
```

So the file.txt should then contains:

```
U00907 - T00977
```

I have tried with a loop but it really does not work:

```
set content=
for /f "delims=;" %%i in (file.txt) do (
  cmd /c exit %%i
  Set "char=!=ExitCodeAscii!"
  set content=%content% %char%
)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Based on your intended txt file output, `U00907 - T00977`, you may need to add additional logic to prevent a `U00907-T00977` result. The sequence has completely ignored your spaces which should have been included in your line. _Your prepended 0's make no difference_ so your line of text should be similar to this: `85;048;048;057;048;055;32;045;32;84;048;048;057;055;055`

Comment: @compo : Observation1: There are two space characters either side of the `045` in the example data - perhaps these are intended literally (whether this is unique to spaces - my crystal ball is a little foggy... Observation2: There is a data element `048`. Need I remind you of the *octal * effect?

Comment: @Magoo, in both the original and edited versions of the question body there appears to be only a single space either side of `045`. My comment wasn't an attempted answer, just a source data correction.

Comment: @compo: Yes - there are two spaces - one space each side of the `045`.  I was probably - well, no "probable" about it - ambiguous there. Interestingly, the `048` is **not** interpreted as octal in an `exit` statement, in fact, the value assigned to *errorlevel* appears decimal for all cases - regardless of the leading `0`. Another quirk for the books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some minor logic failures: with `delims=;` you take only the first token `85` and ignore the rest. You need one loop to get each line of `file.txt` and another loop to process the tokens in each line (a simple `for` without `/f`). And you need [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "delims=" %%i in (file.txt) do (
  set content=
  for %%a in (%%i) do (
    cmd /c exit %%a
    Set "char=!=ExitCodeAscii!"
    set content=!content!!char!
  )
  echo !content:-= - !
)
```

If you are sure, `file.txt` contains only one line (or you don't care about the rest), you can replace the first `for /f` loop with `<file.txt set /p string=` and process that with
`for %%a in (%string%) do (`

Comment: Please see my remarks to Compo on the initial text of the question. I may alter your approach a little.

Comment: Wow, I am impressed. Very quick response in a few hours (minutes). Seems to be the good answer Stephan. I need to test a bit. Thank you very much to Magoo and Compo too..
You save me a lot of time!